# Do I have to release this variable?

Tags: objective-c, release

```
UIViewController *parentController;
for (UIView* next = [self superview]; next; next = next.superview) {
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [next nextResponder];
    if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
        parentController = (UIViewController*)nextResponder;
    }
}
```

In this code, do I have to release the parentController?
Then, when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't take the ownership(retain/alloc/copy/new) of parentController object so you don't have to release it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have release it because you haven't increase it's retain count (by `new`, `alloc`, `retain` or `copy`).

Answer (score 0):

No. You are not taking ownership, so no need to release it either.

Comment: The purpose of your code is a bit of a head scratcher though.

Comment: You seem to be working your way towards a containing view controller breaking proper MVC strucutre. It's usually cleaner to work with pointers to get there.